# Проверить, есть ли во введенных числах две одинаковых цифры

Tags: c#

Есть типа такой номер 224511, он забивается в TexBox. Надо сделать так, чтобы при проверке текста и получении двух одинаковых цифр он ставил символ ##. Как-то так.

Comment: Поточнее описать задачу можете? И писать грамотнее хотя бы попытайтесь.

Также прошу обратить внимание, что за Вас делать работу никто не будет, но подсказать где и в чем ошибка в Ваших собственных наработках, это всегда пожалуйста.

Comment: Нужно создать цикл сравнения. То есть если в виденных числах встречается 2 одинаковых  цифры, то перед ними надо поставить символ #. Что бы получилось так: пример 225788 вели 
##57## получили. Я не прошу решить я прошу направить меня в нужное русло.

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял, вам нужна замена пар подряд идущих одинаковых символов.

```
string str = "2233445123";
char[] strArr = str.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length - 2; i+=2)
{
    if (strArr[i].Equals(str[i + 1]))
    {
        strArr[i] = '#';
        strArr[i + 1] = '#';
    }
}
str = string.Join(string.Empty, strArr);
```

Comment: да имено это СП большое

Comment: @SpiritAT, закрывайте вопросы, если устраивает ответ.

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: btw, контрпримеры к решению:

    99988 - это должно быть ##9##, 9#### или #####
    55555 - это должно быть ####5, 5#### или ##### (тут ещё пару вариантов)

хотя это к автору вопроса:))

Comment: 99988 - это должно быть ##9##

Comment: @SpiritAT, поставить галку рядом с ответом.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать замену при помощи простой регулярки:

```
var rex = new Regex(@"(.)\1");
var replaced = rex.Replace("99988", "##");

Console.WriteLine(replaced); // -> ##9##
```

Демонстрация работы: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xML8n2